# Why Chrome Browser automatically Send Cross Origin Request to http://loadingpages.me/jo/is

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

If I visit `github.com` or any other website, following HTTP request will be sent (as cURL)

```
curl 'http://loadingpages.me/jo/is?id=06EABEDF-9511-5AC0-B879-56F132D94E21&d=3168a8ab-1bcf-41ba-a65d-762b1336fdca&cl=upd' -H 'Referer: https://github.com/' --compressed
```

DNS Response as follow:

---

```
$ nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> loadingpages.me
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   loadingpages.me
Address: 130.117.78.138
```

Comment: Usually it means you have an extension that tracks you.

Comment: Which extension? I disabled every extension in Chrome, but not restart it yet.

Comment: Well then restart the browser. Disabling an extension doesn't unload its content scripts.

Comment: Restarted, but it is still tracking me.

Comment: Maybe you use some weird fork of chromium? Or you didn't disable all extensions? Or maybe you have a browser plugin? Anyway, you can run a global file search on the entire disk for `loadingpages` using a utility that examines hidden and system files.

Comment: Maybe it is a security issue, because I have reinstalled chrome via `brew cask reinstall google-chome`. DANGER !

Comment: `chome` is not `chrome` so you've installed a phishing fork apparently.

Comment: It's just a misspelling of `chrome`.

Comment: https://github.com/nico3333fr/CSP-useful/blob/master/csp-wtf/not-explained.md

Answer (score 2):

You are infected by malware, one which I encountered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288000/found-old-viruses-on-a-computer-running-macos-sierra-what-to-do-now). You'll be happy to know Apple is currently taking no steps whatsoever to remove it from your computer through security updates nor prevent it from contacting `loadingpages.me` without your consent.

Data which is sent to that address may include whatever the malware has been able to gather: a virus that I've found just together with this one included Safari, Firefox and Chrome web data backups to what it was sending home (this might include cookies and browsing history).

You have to run an antivirus immediately, though that may be insufficient if this virus has gone unreported. I recommend [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac-download/) or [Sophos AV](https://home.sophos.com/mac).

Answer (score 1):

It's some kind of malware. Check out `~/Library/` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directories for some strange scripts/apps. By strange i mean weird and unexpected names.

Answer (score 0):

Malware, removed by ... (No Advertisement)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, try find in `~/Library/Caches/org.nn.updater/fsCachedData/` directory strange file with `loadingpaqes.info` inside, I remove this file too

Answer (score -1):

Delete this file : ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ectropium.plist